User-defined pattern vanishing in Adobe when Accessibility option is used
I'm using the TikZ pattern defined here, but experiencing a weird problem.
The minimal tex file I'm having a problem with is the following. When I open the compiled PDF in Adobe, the pattern on the left square disappears if I check "Replace Document Colors" in Edit > Preferences > Accessibility on Adobe.
Any help on how to make it visible?
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\tikzset{
    hatch distance/.store in=\hatchdistance,
    hatch distance=10pt,
    hatch thickness/.store in=\hatchthickness,
    hatch thickness=2pt
}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\hatchdistance,\hatchthickness]{flexible hatch}
{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
{\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}
{\pgfpoint{\hatchdistance-1pt}{\hatchdistance-1pt}}%
{
    \pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchthickness}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[pattern=flexible hatch,pattern color=red] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\draw[pattern=flexible hatch] (1,0) rectangle (2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


I found a workaround as below. "red" doesn't work, but "almost red" does. TeXworks display is still wrong, but on Adobe it looks as intended.
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\tikzset{
    hatch distance/.store in=\hatchdistance,
    hatch distance=10pt,
    hatch thickness/.store in=\hatchthickness,
    hatch thickness=2pt
}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\hatchdistance,\hatchthickness]{flexible hatch}
{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
{\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}
{\pgfpoint{\hatchdistance-1pt}{\hatchdistance-1pt}}%
{
    \pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchthickness}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
}
\makeatother

\definecolor{ared}{rgb}{0.9999,0,0} % almost red

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[pattern=flexible hatch,pattern color=ared] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\draw[pattern=flexible hatch] (1,0) rectangle (2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

